# Close Toggle Other open Divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle

All,
I've got the following code to open some divs that are acting as Toggles:

```
$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".box").hide();
});

$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
     $(this).find(".trigger").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
     });
});
```

Here is my HTML to display the Toggles:

```
<div class="tb-toggle toggle-fancy"><a href="#" class="trigger"><span>+</span>Toggle Accordion</a><div class="box">This is fancy toggle accordion</div><!-- .box (end) --></div>
<div class="tb-toggle toggle-fancy"><a href="#" class="trigger"><span>+</span>Toggle Accordion 2</a><div class="box">This is fancy toggle accordion 2</div><!-- .box (end) --></div>
<div class="tb-toggle toggle-fancy"><a href="#" class="trigger"><span>+</span>Toggle Accordion 3</a><div class="box">This is fancy toggle accordion 3</div><!-- .box (end) --></div>
```

This works fine and opens up my Toggle fine. However, when this happens I'd like close the other open Toggles.

I found this on jQuery http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ so I tried to adjust my code to this:

```
$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
     $(this).find(".trigger").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
     });
}).next().hide();
```

This doesn't work. I think I might have to remove the active toggle class for the other ones but not sure how to do that.

I also tried this bit of code:

```
$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
     $(this).find(".trigger").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
     });
}).next().toggleClass("active");
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is an updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED :) Update after the jsfiddle for specific case** Working demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/2/

**JQuery Code**

```
$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".box").hide();
});

$(".tb-toggle").each(function(){
    $(this).find(".trigger").click(function() {
        $('.tb-toggle a').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().stop(true, true).slideToggle("slow");
        //return false;
    });
});
```

**Previous version when no Jsfiddle was there provided**

Hiya Okies this might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/CzE3q/

**Working demo:** (bit more structured) http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/21/ - Since you have no jsfiddle I will assume your HTML is fine and try this

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks, I this didn't work for me but I added a JS Fiddle for you to look at

Comment: @user1048676 - FIXED now sending you link now!

Comment: just one last question. If I have one open and then click that one again I would expect it to close but it closes and then opens right back up again. How can I fix that?

Comment: @user1048676 Resolved reside here: http://jsfiddle.net/HHtBX/9/ ; Gosh I need + 20 now lolz :)) hope this helps, cheers

Comment: that works perfect! Gave you a vote up again. Best I could do!

Comment: @user1048676 it was a lite humour bruv, have a good one, cheers!